# Write a content to the created txt file

Tags: python

I have a problem in given program the error is shown:

> "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".

Can anyone solve?

```
import os
fd = os.open("f1.txt",os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
ret = os.write(fd,'This is test')
print(f"the number of bytes written: {ret}")
print("written successfully")
os.close(fd)
```

Comment: Either `os.write(fd, b'This is test')` or you have to open the file in text mode.

Comment: its worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`os.write` expects `bytes` not `str`, so the folowing will solve your problem:

```
import os
fd = os.open("f1.txt",os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
ret = os.write(fd,'This is test'.encode())
print(f"the number of bytes written: {ret}")
print("written successfully")
os.close(fd)
```

Comment: @KlausD., you are totally right XD. Thanks! I guess trying to answer multiple questions at the same time led to that confusion.